# Content-Transfer-Encoding in file uploading request

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to upload file, using XMLHTTPRequest, and sending this headers:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data, boundary=xxxxxxxxx

--xxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploadfile'; filename='123_logo.jpg'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/jpeg
/*base64data*/
```

But on server side PHP ignore header "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
and write  base64 undecoded data directly into the file!

Is there any way to fix it?

p.s. it is very important to send data using base64

Comment: Why do you construct the headers manually? Why is it significant to send it base64-encoded rather than binary?

Comment: Because there is no implemented method xhr.sendAsBinary() in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong

`Content-Transfer-Encoding` may appear in the a composite body

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

> There are several consequences of this. The entity-body for composite
>   types MAY contain many body-parts, each with its own MIME and HTTP
>   headers (including Content-MD5, Content-Transfer-Encoding, and
>   Content-Encoding headers).

Comment: Thnx! Using base64_decode  is very ugly method, but i think i have no other choice.

Comment: The older RFC1867 for multipart/form-data is probably also relevant. It mentions Content-Transfer-Encoding for mail transports, but there's no need in HTTP. This is why PHPs `rfc1867.c` does not honor it.

Answer (score 13):

Xavier's answer doesn't sound right. RFC2616 also has this to say (section 3.7):

> In general, HTTP treats a multipart
> message-body no differently than
> any other media type: strictly as
> payload. The one exception is the
> "multipart/byteranges"

It seems to me that section 19.4 of RFC2616 is talking about HTTP as a whole, in the sense that it uses a syntax similar to MIME (like headers format), but is **not** MIME-compliant.

Also, there is [RFC2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt). In [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-3), last paragraph, it says:

> Each part may be encoded and the
> "content-transfer-encoding" header
> supplied if the value of that part
> does not conform to the default
> encoding.

[Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-4.3) elaborates on this:

> #### 4.3 Encoding
>
> While the HTTP protocol can transport arbitrary binary data, the
> default for mail transport is the 7BIT encoding.  The value supplied
> for a part may need to be encoded and the "content-transfer-encoding"
> header supplied if the value does not conform to the default
> encoding.  [See [section 5 of RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5) for more details.]

Comment: Agreed. This is definitely a bug in PHP.  Both the W3C HTML docs and the RFCs you highlight make quite clear that in a POST response to a form, `Content-Transfer-Encoding` may be used.  This makes sense because otherwise text fields might inadvertently include a MIME boundary sequence, and would all have to be sent in binary with a `Content-Length`.

Comment: This isn't a "bug" in PHP, nor is it particular to PHP. From my research into this, it appears multipart POST is a complete mess, IETF RFC are mostly useless and needs to be updated. RFC 2388 needs to be completely overhauled, so does HTML 4.01's http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html reference. Basically. No modern UA use content-transfer-encoding, you must use content-type to determine the encoding. Not only that, charsets is assumed to be the same as the initial requested form's charset, and "multipart/mixed" for multiple files is not used. Just as well; KISS.

Comment: The updated spec https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4.7 also drops `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.