# ab (ApacheBench) image upload and PHP $_FILES - temp file saved as base64 text

Tags: php, post, base64, image-uploading, apachebench

I'm using ApacheBench to benchmark a PHP image upload module. Thing is, when I dump `$_FILES["my_file"]` I can see that the temp file stored by PHP is not an image file, it's a base64 (text/plain) file. Shouldn't PHP be storing that file as an image file, given that the `POST` request is telling it that the uploaded file's content type is `image/jpeg`? Or is PHP behaving as expected and it's my job to handle the binary data inside of `$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"]`?

Here's how I'm running ab:

```
$>ab -v 4 -n 10 -c 2 -p /home/post_data.txt -T "multipart/form-data;\
boundary=1234567890" http://localhost/image_upload
```

Here's the contents of /home/post_data.txt:

```
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"
Content-Type: text/plain

1
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"
Content-Type: text/plain

Testing
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"
Content-Type: text/plain

1
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file"; filename="my_image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

[[base64 image data]]
--1234567890--
```

[Note that I tried removing `"Content-Type: text/plain"` but it seems to make no difference]

Thanks!

Comment: Try one of the following two things for the issue:

1. Use "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" instead of "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
2. Update [[base64 image data]] with [[binary iamge data]]. You can use tools like WinHex / UltraEdit to write the binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Rachel! I tried both suggestions without success. [Apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169434/content-transfer-encoding-in-file-uploading-request) PHP is ignoring the header (Content-Transfer-Encoding) from my request. Oh, and check [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48219) too!

Comment: Lol, [this one](http://galleryproject.org/node/22724) dates back to 2004...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally given up on this one: PHP ignores the header (`Content-Transfer-Encoding`) and I end up with a text file containing a huge string of binary data instead of an image file.

Not AB's fault...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to perform the task by adding image binary directly to post_data file.

```
cat image.jpeg >> post_data
```

The content of post_data file looks like this.

```
--123456789
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

"binary content goes here"
--123456789
```

And make sure that your post_data has CRLF file ending instead of LF.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

Adding `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` solved this.

---

## Full answer:

Full `post-data.txt` file, with `CRLF` endings:

```
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[base64 encoded image here]

--1234567890--
```

Full command:

```
$ ab -c 5 -n 5 -p ./post_data.txt -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890" http://localhost:8080/upload
```

---

## Error origin:

Encountered this error while using Flask with `imageio.imread(file)` which resulted in error `Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'`